# Как убрать выравнивание по центру?

Tags: html, css

Пациент: http://prob.obmenniki.pp.ua/mashinnaya-shtukaturka.html
Не могу найти, почему все содержимое блока `<div id="content">` выравнивает по центру...
Кажется, уже все перерыл... ((((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У body уберите text-align: center;